# How to set up a Google Checkout merchant account in a non-US country?

Tags: google-account, google-checkout

I am a Canadian resident looking to sell paid apps on the Google Play store. According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/register.html):

> "If you want to sell products on Google Play — priced apps, in-app products, or subscriptions — you will also need to set up a Google Checkout Merchant Account."

Fair enough. So I clicked on the provided link and landed on a page offering to sign me up for a new Google account or "use an existing Google account with Checkout".

After clicking the link to use my existing account, I ended up on a page with a sign-up form and the text:

> "We do not currently support seller accounts from this location. If you have an existing Wallet account, please use the Wallet settings page to change your country of residence."

This didn't sound good. But then I found [this page](https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134420):

> "Merchants in ... Canada, ... can also use Google Checkout to sell applications on Google Play."

There was a link on that page directing me to sign up for Google Wallet, which I was able to do without any problems.

So my question is... how do I get everything set up properly to sell my apps? Do I need anything more than a Google Wallet account? Do I need a merchant account?

Answer (score 1):

At this time Canada is a supported location according to [Supported locations for developer & merchant registration](https://support.google.com/payments/merchant/table/3539140?hl=en&ref_topic=4490611) for

- Google Play Developer Registration
- Merchant Registration